# show picture in django

Tags: django

I have a new django project **project1**.It contains basic files of django(settings.py,urls.py,views.py).then I put imgs in **project1/static/img/**,such as 11.jpeg

now I want to show this picutre in a url request(like **http://host:port/path/to/img**);or something like a response that return a template which contains `<img src='...'/>`

I tried many ways and nothing works

does anyone can give me some suggest,or some simple code

thanks advance!

Comment: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/staticfiles/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What version of django are you using?

in 1.4 you can do this in your template:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}hi.jpg" />
```

or

```
<img src="../static/hi.jpg" />
```

and in your settings.py:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/YOURUSERNAME/Desktop/YOURPROJECTNAME/static'
^^^ this just has to be the path to the static directory in your project ^^^

MEDIA_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/media/'
```

then in your urls.py:

```
if settings.DEBUG: urlpatterns += patterns('', (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}), )
```

Comment: MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'static').replace('\\','/')  MEDIA_URL = '/static/'  STATIC_ROOT = ''  STATIC_URL = '/media/' .and my template is <img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}11.JPG" mce_src="{{ STATIC_URL }}11.JPG" width="1240" height="949"> . urlpatterns = patterns('',                      (r'^showimg/$',showImg)) ,but it doesn't work error:GET /showimg/11.JPG HTTP/1.1" 404 1942

Comment: here is a sample:

template:
<img src="../static/python.jpeg" alt="python_logo">

settings.py:
MEDIA_ROOT = '/Users/louisciampanelli/Desktop/programming/Django/simpleBlog/static'

MEDIA_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = ''

STATIC_URL = '/media/'
urls.py:
if settings.DEBUG:
    urlpatterns += patterns('',
        (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    )

Answer (score 0):

This is what u need i guess:

```
<img src="{{ STATIC_URL }}img/11.jpeg" />
```